# javascript how to return a number from an object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a large object called `con` in that object, I have many variables, numbered sort of like an excel sheet, `b19, b20, b21, etc.`

I am trying to return a value from each one, but when I do a console log, It logs the entire function, not just the return.

Here's how the object is set up:

```
var con = {
    b13: function(){
        return 12600.535*Math.sqrt((con.b14+459.4)/459.4)
    },
    b14: function(){
        return 20;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(con.b13);
});
```

This outputs this into the console:

```
function(){
    return 12600.535*Math.sqrt((con.b14+459.4)/459.4)
}
```

So how do I format this so that it outputs the actual number in the equation?

Comment: console.log(con.b13()); Similarly, you will have to call the function b14 within b13 as con.b14()

Comment: The `defineProperty` syntax is quite verbose, but you can actually declare getters/setters through the object literal syntax. Check my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `b13` and `b14` *properties* with a getter function:

```
var con = {};

Object.defineProperty(con, "b13", {
    get: function() {
        return 12600.535*Math.sqrt((con.b14+459.4)/459.4);
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(con, "b14", {
    get: function() { return 20; }
});
```

This will cause `con.b13` and `con.b14` to call the given functions, returning whatever the functions return.

Comment: This is probably the proper and best way to do it, though the simple fix to just give a `()` at the end of the variable name works perfectly.

Comment: @ntgCleaner You use properties when the function represents *data*, and regular functions when the function represents an *action*.  In this case they represent data, so property syntax should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.log(con.b13());` .  You are logging the function definition not executing it.

Answer (score 1):

you don't define the properties as functions...

```
var con = {
  b13: 239487,
  b12: 923748
};
```

edit: if some properties need to be functions you have to call them e.g. con.b14(), not con.b14 as a property

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use es5 getters/setters.

```
var con = {
    get b13() {
        return 12600.535*Math.sqrt((con.b14+459.4)/459.4);
    },
    get b14() {
        return 20;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your object's properties are `functions`, but you are trying to call them as if they were `values`.

For example, if you wanted correctly log `con.b13`'s value to the console, you would need to change the command to:

```
console.log(con.b13());
```

What this does is get what `con.b13` *returns* rather than what it *is*.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of adding a `()` next to every reference, you can modify the object and define `getters` like this:

```
var con = {
    get b13() {
        return 12600.535 * Math.sqrt((con.b14 + 459.4) / 459.4)
    },

    get b14() {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

If you define the object like this, your original command `console.log(con.b13)` will work as intended.